# How to get Body of the email using c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to get the email body from my Gmail account for an email so i use this code i found it in an example for how to read emails using c++ builder pop3
the code to extract body used

```
TIdText *EText;
int message = SpinEdit1->Value;
MyPoP3->Retrieve(message, MyEmail);
Edit1->Text = MyEmail->Subject + " | " + MyEmail->From->Address;
Memo1->Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < MyEmail->MessageParts->Count; i++) {
    Memo1->Lines->Add(MyEmail->MessageParts->Items[i]->ContentType);
    EText = dynamic_cast<TIdText*>(MyEmail->MessageParts->Items[i]);
    Memo1->Lines->Add(EText->Body);
}
```

the problem is that i got undefine symbol to TidText and what i tried is to change it from `TIdText` to `TIdMessage`, but i got that i can't convert to it.
also i tried to try this without loop or something `MyEmail->Body->Text`
this return empty string.
the video i got this code from it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xg8hKNqhXng) i don't know maybe the c++ builder he use is old. now i want to know how to extract the body text from the email address.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that i got undefine symbol to TidText

Your code is missing an `#include <IdText.hpp>` statement.

> what i tried is to change it from `TIdText` to `TIdMessage`, but i got that i can't convert to it.

Because `TIdMessage` does not contain nested `TIdMessage` objects.

> also i tried to try this without loop or something `MyEmail->Body->Text` this return empty string.

If your email is MIME encoded, its text is not stored in the `TIdMessage::Body` property, but in a nested `TIdText` object within the `TIdMessage::MessageParts` collection. You have to look at the `TIdMessage::ContentType` property to know what kind of structure the email contains. For instance, if the CT begins with `text/`, the text is in the `TIdMessage::Body`. But if the CT begins with `multipart/`, the text is somewhere in the `TIdMessage::MessageParts` instead.

You should read this blog article on Indy's website for an example of how emails might be structured:

[HTML Messages](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.EN.aspx)

> the video i got this code from it here i don't know maybe the c++ builder he use is old.

No, it is not.